# Dynamically do postback

Tags: vb.net, postback

Is it possible to do postback dynamically in vb.net or c#.net?

THere is a asp button (let say buttonA) if i click buttonA it has to do some actions and then trigger postback

postback should not be triggered onclicking a button . only after performing some actions it has to trigger postback

i have searched for almost a day but couldnt find any solution pls help

THanks a lot
caty

Answer (score 3):

By deafult all asp buttons do postback. If you want to perform some client side function before the postback just add it to the `OnClientClick` property and return `true` or `false` from the function depending if you want a postback or not.

```
<asp:Button ID="Btn1" OnClientClick="return MyFunction();" />

function MyFunction()
{
    alert('test');
    return true; //Do postback
}
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks everyone, finally i found the solution

on button click i perform some action then call js function using below code

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "postback", "postback();", True)
```

`postback()` is the JS function which performs postback

```
function postback()
{

    document.form1.submit(); //postback

}
```

Cheers,
Catty

Answer (score 0):

Call following JS from client sode to postback.

```
Response.Write("<script>document.forms[0].submit();</script>");
```

or call from JS at the moment you want postback.

```
__doPostBack(id,'');
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is attach a client-script to the OnClientClick event of the ASP.NET button.

```
<asp:Button ID="MyButton" OnClientClick="return MyButton_ClientClick()" Text="Click Me" runat="server" />
```

Then your JavaScript function will look like this:

```
function MyButton_ClientClick()
{
   ...
   __doPostback();
}
```

Not the best solution, but at least it gives you an idea of how to proceeed.